# Open browser with a url with extra headers for Android

Tags: java, android, uri

I have a specific requirement where I have to fire a url on the browser from my activity. I am able to do this with the following code :

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(
  Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(
    pref.getString("webseal_sso_endpoint", "") + "?authorization_code="
      + code + "&webseal-ip=" + websealIP
  )
);

activity.startActivity(browserIntent);
activity.finish();
```

Now, I want to invoke this webseal_sso_endpoint by passing an extra header. say
("user":"username")
How can I implement this?
Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I featured out how to add a header. Here is my code:

```
        Intent browserIntent = new Intent(
                Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle(); 
        bundle.putString("iv-user", username); 
        browserIntent.putExtra(Browser.EXTRA_HEADERS, bundle);
        activity.startActivity(browserIntent);
        activity.finish();
```

Comment: So I'm able to add "Authorization" string to the "headers" using this construct.

Comment: Will it work for non-Chromium browsers? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38438069/adding-custom-headers-on-all-browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Recommended method to do this would be to use the Uri class to create your URI.  Helps ensure that everything is defined correctly and associates the correct key to value for your URI.

For example, you want to send a Web intent with this URL:

```
http://webseal_sso_endpoint?authorization_code=SomeCode&webseal-ip=WEBSEALIP
```

And you have a defined URL and parameters you want to send, you should declare these as static final fields, like so:

```
private final static String BASE_URL = "http://webseal_sso_endpoint";
private final static String AUTH_CODE = "authorization_code";
private final static String IP = "webseal-ip";  
private final static String USERNAME = "user";
```

You can then use these, like so:

```
Uri builtUri = Uri.parse(BASE_URL).buildUpon()
    .appendQueryParameter(AUTH_CODE, code)
    .appendQueryParameter(IP, websealIP)
    .build();
```

Now if you want to add another parameter, add another appendQueryParameter, like so:

```
Uri builtUri = Uri.parse(BASE_URL).buildUpon()
    .appendQueryParameter(AUTH_CODE, code)
    .appendQueryParameter(IP, websealIP)
    .appendQueryParameter(USERNAME, user)
    .build();
```

You can convert to a URL if needed using:

```
URL url = new URL(builtUri.toString());
```

Should come out like this:

```
http://webseal_sso_endpoint?authorization_code=SomeCode&webseal-ip=WEBSEALIP&user=SomeUsersName
```

Comment: just appending string behind doesnot work. otherwise I can just append more attribute inside Uri.parse(
                        pref.getString("webseal_sso_endpoint", "") +"?authorization_code="+ code +"&webseal-ip="+ websealIP). But thank you any way for your answre

Comment: Ah, maybe I misunderstood your goal.  Are you trying to create a session between the app and server?  Or something else?  Could you edit the original question and provide an example or clarification?